# Class 'List<String>' has no instance method 'contain'

Tags: flutter, dart

I store data with the Flutter Hive package.
When checking my list for an element, Flutter throws the following `NoSuchMethodError`:

```
E/flutter (22594): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)]
Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class 'List<String>' has no instance method 'contain'.
```

Why is `contain` not working?

```dart
if (!Hive.box("monthDataList").get("monthDataListKey").contain(dateTimeindex)) ...
```

Comment: How about replacing `contain` with `contains`?

Comment: that was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [`Iterable.contains`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/contains.html) instead of `contain`.
It checks if the given element can be found in the collection:

```dart
if (!list.contains(dateTimeIndex)) ...
```

[`List`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List-class.html) *extends* `Iterable`, which is why your `List<String>` object has a `contains` instance method.